# Run php composer without any output

Tags: php, centos, composer-php

I had composer v.1.3.2, today I updated it to 1.4.1, after done, I run 'composer' as usual but see nothing output. My php version is 7.1.3. OS is CentOS 7 in vagrant. (Composer below is composer.phar 1.4.1)
[image]

I've tried rm composer cache and re-download composer.phar. Even composer 1.3.2 can not work now.

Unexpected I found composer.phar can run by PHP v7.0.

Then I upload the same composer.phar to another CentOS 7 which has php v7.1.3. Composer works well there.
[image]

Have any idea about it? Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the composer file have the right permission ?

Comment: @hassan may be right, will composer run in the second example if you are not acting as root? (And vice versa if you run the first example **with** root privileges).

Comment: Thanks for you response. I'm sure the composer has x and I'm act as root.       

[root@taoquan vagrant]# whoami
root
[root@taoquan vagrant]# whereis composer
composer: /usr/local/bin/composer
[root@taoquan vagrant]# ls /usr/local/bin/composer -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1836198 Apr 26 14:30 /usr/local/bin/composer